# Using setTimeout to skip first occurrence

Tags: javascript

I wish to execute `console.log();` only after the time has expired and then repeat, but not immediately upon page load.  How is this accomplished?

```
function setTimer(t) {
  (function timeout() {
    console.log('timer '+t+' seconds')
    setTimeout(timeout, t*1000);
  })();
}

setTimer(5);
setTimer(10);
setTimer(15);
setTimer(20);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y969uLhx/

Comment: Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) in combination with `document.ready` callback.

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov  `setInterval` has its issues, and I don't wish to use it.

Comment: Why the markdowns?

Answer (score 1):

Using only **setInterval** :

You can use **setInterval** which will execute again and again in predefined periods.The below example will print 'Hello there' every second.

```
var myID = setInterval(function(){
  console.log('Hello there');
},1000);
```

To stop the setInterval you need to use the following :

```
clearInterval(myID);
```

---

Using only **setTimeout**:

You can also use **setTimeout** and call a function that will call itself. The below Example will execute **after 1 second** and then repeat every second printing "Hello There" in your console.

```
    setTimeout(function(){
      CallMyself();
    },
 // Set the Execution to take place exactly 1000 ms after it has been called.
    1000);

    function CallMyself(){
      console.log('Hello There');
      setTimeout(function(){
        CallMyself();
      },
  // Set the period of each loop to be 1000 ms
     1000);
    }
```

---

Using **both combined** :

You can also combine **setInterval** and **setTimeOut**. The below example will start printing "Hello There" every second **after** 1 second has passed.

```
  setTimeout(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log('Hello there');
    },1000);
  },1000);
```

---

Example of a function that takes initial Delay and Loop Delay as arguments so that you can create different Timers :

```
//  First argument is the Delay in Execution. 
//  Second argument is the period it takes for each loop to be completed.
```

```js
    setCustomTimer(1 , 2);
    setCustomTimer(2 , 4);
    
    function setCustomTimer( initialDelay , LoopDelay ){
      console.log('Initial Delay of ' + initialDelay + ' Seconds');
      
      var myDelay = LoopDelay;
      
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Initial Delay of ' + initialDelay + ' seconds is Over.      Starting Loop. ');
        CallMyself(myDelay);
      },initialDelay * 1000);
    }
    
    function CallMyself(LoopDelay){
      console.log('Loop every ' + LoopDelay + ' Seconds');
      setTimeout(function(){
        CallMyself(LoopDelay);
      },LoopDelay * 1000);
    }
```

Comment: How is it accomplished using `setTimeout()` (your second example)?  It executes immediately which is specifically what I wish to prevent.

Comment: setTimeOut executes according to the value you pass to it. In my examples the setTimeOut executes 1 second after it has been called. Nevertheless i have added a small portion of code that you can tweak to your needs. Check the 2nd Example.

Comment: Humm  Two `setTimeout()` functions.  It looks a little complicated, and might use your first approach but slightly modified.  https://jsfiddle.net/2f0kq2u8/.  Not sure yet how it will work with my example where I have an arbitrary number of timers to set up (i.e. 5, 10, 15, and 20 seconds in the example I showed, but there might be more and not on such consecutive time periods).

Comment: Two setTimeouts is not an issue , the first one is there just for a simple delay. I have added a function at the 4th example , check it out. You should be able to go on from there and expand to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
function MyLoop(t) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Loop '+t+' seconds.')
    MyLoop(t);
  }, t * 1000);
}

MyLoop(5);
MyLoop(10);
MyLoop(15);
MyLoop(20);
```